# Detect device or OS from browser agent string

Tags: regex, operating-system, user-agent

I would like to make the best estimate on what device or OS a visitor is using.

The only categories I'm interested in distinguishing, are:

- Android
- iOS
- Windows Phone
- Desktop (Windows / OS X / Linux)
- Other / unkown / undetected (like search spiders or whatever)

It's not security related, so I don't mind about the risk of agent string spoofing. It's just to provide visitors with an immediate suggestion for their particular device.

I happen to work in PHP currently, but any language would do, I assume it just boils down to a bunch of regular expressions to be matched against the browser agent string.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, that's what it boils down to. At my previous job I had a perl script for analyzing Apache log files, and over 1,000 lines of it were analyzing user agent strings, although the script went into much greater detail than you need. For what you need, simple things like /iPhone|iPad/ and /Android/ should do, although you might want to look over what appears in user agent strings, for example at http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/All/.

Comment: Thanks, however the list on that page seems to focus on the type of *browser*, whereas I just need to OS. Knowing that it's Firefox doesn't help me much, as that can still be Android, iOS, Linux, etc. Especially telling Windows (desktop) from Windows Phone seems tricky? And there are browsers that contain "Apple", "Linux" and "Android" all in one and the same agent string, no clue how to deal with those?

Comment: Yes, I pointed you to that list to demonstrate the wide range of user agent strings. Desktop Windows vs mobile Windows is tricky, you'll need to test for things like /Windows (Phone|Mobile|CE)/ and then just plain /Windows/, in that order. There are lots of strings that contain "Apple" because they use Apple's WebKit, so instead look for /Mac OS X/. Also, if you split the user agent string on ";", the third field will often (but not always, for example recent Safaris) contain the OS. There isn't a perfect solution unfortunately.